# How to send an automatic email at a click of a button?

Tags: php, javascript, html, email, spam

I'm creating a page with 4 buttons (the buttons will be 4 different images), so when you press any one of the buttons, an email is sent to the appropriate department.

For example, button 1 is for Math department, when you press button 1, an email is sent automatically to math@uni.com, press button 2, an email is automatically sent to music@uni.com and so on.

This project will be using a subdomain on my work's website eg xxx.ourcompany.com How can I send an email automatically with a click of one of the four buttons using html, php or javascript if necessary?

**(Ignore below if you have better ideas on how to do the task above, or it would be great if you could help me on the below issue)** this is what I've found so far:

I saw a post that someone suggested the code below. I tried to duplicate the code for four buttons, but the email can't be sent to every mail address from the subdomain (xxx.ourcompany.com).

Issue: The only email address is receiving the notification is an email address with our company's name in it eg name@ourcompany.com but not yahoo or gmail account. I'm not sure what the reason is? Also what is a good way to stop spam as well? Your help is really appreciated.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Send details to A" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_a" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_a']))
{

$to      = 'name@ourcompany.com'; //can receive notification

$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

I duplicate the code for the second button, but the yahoo or gmail email address can't receive notification

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Send details to B" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_b" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_b']))
{

$to      = 'name@yahoo.com'; //can't receive notification!

$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

Comment: if this "automation" were possible (it is, but not advisable), we'd be collecting thousands of spam everyday.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks very much for your reply. What do you reckon is a better way to do it? I'm still learning on it. Thanks very much, S:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your emails are considered spam. Web mail providers like Gmail and Yahoo only receive email if they think the source is trustworthy. i get that a lot of times, when a co-worker emails me to my personal email using his company email. it always ends up in the spam.

and consider that your page is online, anyone can hack into it, and send spam all over your company using those one-click emailers you're trying to create.

how about concentrating on building  sort of inter-department messaging system. you'd have to enforce the departments to subscribe to this, maybe build a desktop app or web app for it so they see the messages easily. it's better this way, sort of an "in-house twitter".

or use twitter instead! :D

or, i think this is possible, use an email client, and one company email. i think email clients today have "templates".

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you are trying to send an email from a server that's not trusted by gmail or yahoo et al. Check the spam folders. Some e-mails don't even get to the spam folders.

Comment: Hi Alfa, thanks for your reply. No spam was in the folder. Any suggestion on how can I achieve what I'm aiming for without the spam problems ect? Thanks very much, S:)

Comment: You might want to use a webhosting service that is trusted, most of paid hostings are, that will be a cheap and easy solution, but of course don't forget about security.

Answer (score 0):

The header was not specified as array. Keep a dot in between header and equals sign. 
Example 4 of this page works like charm

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

As told anyways the email will be considered as spam and the receiver need to update its not a spam.